# How can you write a .mov file with libav which is playable if the file isn't properly completed

Tags: c++, c, libav

I'm developing a video recording application in c++ with the libav c library which records and encodes h265 from a camera feed into a .mov container.

I can successfully play back the .mov file on all standard video players, but only if the recording is terminated properly - i.e. calling `av_write_trailer` and properly closing the file.

One important requirements of the software, however, is a playable .mov file even in the event that the recording is terminated inappropriately - i.e. power loss or target disk becomes full.

I'm assuming this is possible as most video recording devices create valid .mov files even when they run out of battery or fill their target media.

I have tried specifying the following `AVDictionary` option which is suppose to move relevant stream information to the start of the file:

`av_dict_set(&options, "movflags", "faststart", 0);`

However, this does not make incomplete files playable.

Comment: I think `av_dict_set(&options, "movflags", "+frag_keyframe+empty_moov+faststart", 0)` is what you're looking for. At least that's what they use for [streaming mp4](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/web_video_server/html/h264__streamer_8cpp_source.html).

Comment: @AlexSkalozub You should write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the options you're looking for:

```
av_dict_set(&options, "movflags", "+frag_keyframe+empty_moov+faststart", 0);
```

This is what is used for [streaming mp4](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/web_video_server/html/h264__streamer_8cpp_source.html), so the stream is both playable and interruptible at any time.

As a downside, such video file won't be seekable. But you can probably post-process such incomplete files and fix headers once the power is restored.

Comment: Most, but not all players will play a fragmented mp4.

Comment: Thanks, the fragmented features does address the issue correctly - but I couldn't play the resulting .mov on any official quicktime based players. The file only played back on libav based players (VLC/MPC-HC). Is it possible that the fragmentation feature is valid for mp4 but not mov?